# web3js connection plug-in wallet

Tags: web3js, metamask

How to let Dapp connect to the specified plug-in wallet on the computer? For example, when I click the tokenPocket icon on the Dapp page, tokenPocket will be automatically connected, and when I click the metamask icon on the Dapp page, metamask can be automatically connected.

I tried using **window.ethereum.request({method:"eth_requestAccounts"})** to connect, but it could not specify the plug-in wallet I need to connect to. If both **tokenPocket** and **metamask** exist, there will be an option in **tokenPocket** to indicate whether you want to use which wallet. However, the method provided by **tokenPocket** cannot allow dapp to automatically select a wallet, but manually. So is there any other way to determine and then automatically connect to the designated wallet?